# Building SSAS 2016 from Visual Studio CLI

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ssas, sql-server-data-tools, ssas-tabular

SSAS projects can't be built using `MSBuild`. However, SSAS projects can reportedly be built using Visual Studio or [SSAS Helper](http://sqlsrvanalysissrvcs.codeplex.com/releases/view/22769) ([description](http://www.ssas-info.com/analysis-services-tools/1745-ssas-helper)).

Using the Visual Studio GUI (`devenv.exe`), the build of my SSAS 2016 Tabular project does indeed build fine:

[image: Build results of a SSAS Tabular 2016 project in Visual Studio]

Visual Studio also provides a CLI for non-interactive use: `devenv.com` . However, although my project builds fine using the GUI, it throws an error when trying to build using the CLI:

[image: devenv.com build throws error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"]

How do I build my SSAS 2016 Tabular projects using the CLI? Does `devenv.com` use another library for building than `devenv.exe`?

## Background / more information / tries:

The SSAS Helper Sample CLI yields the same error.

[The internet doesn't seem to know about this problem](https://www.google.nl/search?q=%22Object%20reference%20not%20set%20to%20an%20instance%20of%20an%20object%22%20%2B%22.smproj%22)..

My smproj file looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Development</Configuration>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{8CE414BB-95B2-4C99-9E03-51BA72086E22}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>MyRootNamespace</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>MyAssemblyName</AssemblyName>
    <EnableUnmanagedDebugging>false</EnableUnmanagedDebugging>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <Name>ProjectName_Tabular</Name>
    <DeploymentServerName>devserver</DeploymentServerName>
    <DeploymentServerEdition>Developer</DeploymentServerEdition>
    <DeploymentServerVersion>Version_11_0</DeploymentServerVersion>
    <DeploymentServerDatabase>ProjectName_Tabular</DeploymentServerDatabase>
    <DeploymentServerCubeName>Model</DeploymentServerCubeName>
    <DeploymentOptionProcessing>Default</DeploymentOptionProcessing>
    <DeploymentOptionTransactionalDeployment>False</DeploymentOptionTransactionalDeployment>
    <DeploymentOptionDirectQueryMode>InMemory</DeploymentOptionDirectQueryMode>
    <DeploymentOptionQueryImpersonation>Default</DeploymentOptionQueryImpersonation>
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Development' ">
    <OutputPath>bin\Development\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DeploymentServerEdition>Enterprise</DeploymentServerEdition>
    <DeploymentOptionProcessing>Full</DeploymentOptionProcessing>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="ProjectName_Tabular.bim">
      <SubType>Code</SubType>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Business Intelligence Semantic Model\1.0\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.VSHostBuilder.targets" />
</Project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With tabular, you can run msbuild. For example,

msbuild TabularProject8.smproj /verbosity:m /target:Rebuild /property:Configuration=Release

Comment: This is a great workaround! Although `devenv.com` should work like `devenv.exe` IMHO, at least this can help me build my solutions (together with [IntegrationServices.Build.dll for SSIS projects](https://speaksql.wordpress.com/2013/06/07/a-journey-to-db-deployment-automaton-ssis-build-using-msbuild/))

Comment: I don't have experience with devenv.exe, but the note at the top of this page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7(v=vs.140).aspx  says for build-related tasks, it is now recommended that you use MSBuild instead of devenv